# codeigniter and jquery user authetication

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, authentication

I am trying to make user authentication with CodeIgniter and jQuery. I have managed to do the following: If user type wrong user name or password, he remain on the login page and with use of jquery, he get notification that he entered wrong user name or password.

My problem is on success, that is if he type correct user name and password, I manage to send the user on the login page with simple javascript redirect, but that is not what i want. If I use simple redirect with javascript, i can't fill the user session data, which I need to track the user after the login on all other pages.

I would like if that is possible, if user enter correct user name and password, jquery to do nothing, and function to be activated only in case that user enter wrong user name or password, if that is possible.

Here is the code that I have. JS code first:

```
 formLogin.on('submit', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type     : 'POST',
    url      : 'loginCheck',
    data     : formLogin.serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(r) {


        if (r.status) {
            // this works, but I would like this part to do nothing
            // just to leave my PHP controller to redirect the user
            window.location = 'http://www.linkedin.com';

        } else {
            $('#errorMessageTop').fadeIn();

        }

    }
});

});
```

And the controller code is:

```
public function loginCheck()
    { 

       // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {

            $ids=array();
            $ids[0]=$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $ids[1] = $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();

            if($query)
                {
                    $data = array(
                    'username'       => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'isUserLoggedIn' => true
                    ); 
                $isAuthenticated = true;
                if ($isAuthenticated) {
                 $return['status']  = true;
                $return['message'] = 'You have successfully been logged in!'; 
                exit(json_encode($return)); 
                 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                $data['title'] = "Welcome to dashboard!";
                $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
                $this->load->vars($data);
                $this->load->view('backOffice/template');


                }

        } else {   

                $return = array(
                'status'  => false,
                'message' => 'Wrong Username or Password'
                );
                 exit(json_encode($return));

        }
        } else {

             $errorMessage = "Second Message Wrong username or pwd...!";
             $errorMessage = json_encode($errorMessage);

        }



    } // end of function loginCheck
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards,Zoran

===============

New code from controller:

```
public function loginCheck()
    { 

       // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {

            $ids=array();
            $ids[0]=$this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $ids[1] = $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();

            if($query)
                {
                    $data = array(
                    'username'       => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'isUserLoggedIn' => true
                    );


                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
                $data['title'] = "Welcome to dashboard!";
                $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard';
                $this->load->vars($data);
                $this->load->view('backOffice/template');


        } else {   

                echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong credentials"));

        }
        } else {

             $errorMessage = "Second Message Wrong username or pwd...!";
             $errorMessage = json_encode($errorMessage);

        }



    } // end of function loginCheck
```

And the js code:

```
  $("#formLogin").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var username = $(this).find("#username").val();
        var password = $(this).find("#password").val();
        var obj = {username: username, password: password};
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.post(url, obj, function(r){
            if(r.success) window.location.replace('http://www.linkedin.com');
            else  $('#errorMessageTop').fadeIn();
        }, 'json');
    })
```

Comment: Where do you want to redirect user after success? If no where then just remove that code

Comment: Removing the code just cause the user to remain stucked on login page, due the prevent default I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `exit()`?... That terminates the script and prevents the session from being set. Also, you're setting `$isAuthenticated` to `true` and immediately checking to see if it's `true`. Of course it will be.

This is a stripped-down version of how I handle it... In my Controller:

```
function take_creds(){

        $p = $this->input->post();
        if($p){
            $u = new User();
            $u->where("username", $p['username']);
            $u->where("password", sha1($p['password']));
            $u->get();
            if($u->exists()){
                $u->loggedin = 1;
                $u->save();

                $data = array(
                    'username' => $u->username,
                    'loggedin' => true
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
            }
            else echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong credentials"));   
        }
    }
```

And the corresponding jQuery:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var username = $(this).find("#login_username").val();
            var password = $(this).find("#login_password").val();
            var obj = {username: username, password: password};
            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            $.post(url, obj, function(r){
                if(r.success) window.location.replace('home');
                else console.log("Write this error to the DOM: " + r.error);
            }, 'json');
        })
```

Comment: Hi Jordan. Thanks for your answer. I have a question...where you will set user session data then, if you redirect the user directly from the javascript? I can send the user directly to the dashboard, but i want to save the username, and to set isLoggedin = true. If I just sent the user to dashboard, i will do nothing then. Anyone who type dashboard.php will be logged in then. Or I am wrong?

Comment: Sorry...i just notice that in your code you are saving the session data. I guess it work from there on once when is set up. I will try your code now.

Comment: @Zoran the Dashboard controller should check to make sure that the user is logged in before you render views, output data, etc. The best way to do this IMO is to create a super controller called `MY_In_Controller`, put the "is user logged in?" check in it's constructor and then have all controllers inherit from this super controller. See [Keeping It Dry](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY). In short -- users who type the dashboard controller into their URL bar will be immediately kicked out because their session will not exist. Does this help?

Comment: I still can not make it to work...even with your code, on submit, form does not go anywhere....stay on login page. How can I post the new code here?

Comment: In the main post, I just add the new code beloow of my name. Can you take a look and see why form doesn't go anywhere when right user name and password are entered???

Comment: You sure it's posting to the proper url? The url is extracted from the `action` attribute of the `form` element from: `var url = $(this).attr("action");` Do you have the `action` filled out in your HTML's `<form>` element? Also, you can inspect the response of an ajax request by opening Chrome Web Tools (ctrl+shift+j) and using the Network tab.

Comment: Furthermore there are still issues with the additional code you've posted. You should not be rendering an entire view with `$data['title'] = "Welcome to dashboard!"; $data['main_content'] = 'dashboard'; $this->load->vars($data); $this->load->view('backOffice/template');`. This is specifically the code that should go into your Dashboard controller (which javascript redirects to). You should only return json_encoded objects from AJAX requests. Currently you're echoing out a mish-mash of json_encoded success object + a load of HTML.

Comment: Form is like this:  $param = 'id="formLogin"';
                    echo form_open('backOffice/loginCheck', $param);

Comment: In the source action is rendered normally.

Comment: Indeed, after checking the networking tab, under preview, html code has been returned. I remove everything from the controller, and i have there only:$this->load->view('backOffice/dashboard'); and i now the dasboard as simple page, without header and footer, but still is the same, after the submit, I remain stucked on login page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15807/discussion-between-jordan-arseno-and-zoran)